# convert WPF WebBrowser to WinForms

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am trying to convert a WPF WebBrowser control to a WinForms WebBrowser control using this code:

```
System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser wb = myWebBrowser as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
```

I am getting this error:

> "Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser' to 'System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion"

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot convert between these two classes.  They are completely separate implementations, one for WPF, and one for Windows Forms.

If you must use a Windows Forms WebBrowser, you'll need to instance one from scratch, and copy individual settings across as required.

Answer (score 1):

wpf and winforms controls are very different (apples and oranges) and can't be converted between each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) to add WPF System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser to WinForms Form.

But I have no idea why you would want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't : they are 2 completely different class hierarchies (apparently both wrappers around an ActiveX component)

If you are desperate, you may try getting information through the Handle field, but this will put you in unmanaged land.